# How to get my Vim and MacVim to find python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, macvim

When I use a plugin that requires python, it can't find it and barfs.

The places that seem to being searched are:

[image]

Using `-version` I see both:

```
+python/dyn        
+python3/dyn
```

However `:echo has("python3")` returns `0`.

I'm not sure if this is compile time config, or runtime-configurable via `.vimrc`.

I'm not a python developer, and the few times I've ventured into that world were in the middle of the python2/python3 mess that turned me off completely. I've played around enough to have configured `pyenv` it seems, and get

```
╰─$ which python
/Users/benlieb/.pyenv/shims/python

╰─$ python --version
Python 3.10.3
```

Can anyone help shed light on what to do to get python3 findable/usable in my vim?

Update:

Following @romainl's suggestion below I set in my `.vimrc`

```
set pythonthreedll=/Users/benlieb/.pyenv/shims/python
```

But getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I found the following works, thought it was not a fun path of discovery.

```
let &pythonthreedll = trim(system("pyenv which python"))
```

Comment: Sweet! I am using `conda` so I slightly changed it in `&pythonthreedll = trim(system("which python"))` . Moreover, but I don't know if it is correct, I also set this: `&pythonthreehome = fnamemodify(trim(system("which python")), ":h:h")`. Tested and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

`+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn` are described here: `:help python-dynamic`.

By default, `:help 'pythonthreedll'` points to:

```
/opt/homebrew/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python
```

because MacVim is built against that version. The message in your screenshot says that there is nothing at that path. In order to have a working Python 3 interface, you can either:

- install Python 3.10 via homebrew,
- or point `pythonthreedll` to a valid path.

For example, I don't use Homebrew so the default value is useless to me, but I use MacPorts so this is my `pythonthreedll`:

```
set pythonthreedll=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/libpython3.10.dylib
```

Comment: I tried setting `set pythonthreedll=/Users/benlieb/.pyenv/shims/python` but got error. I updated my question with the error. I guess it needs the actual executable?

Comment: You should try with the exact path to the dll.

Comment: I was able to get this working with `let &pythonthreedll = trim(system("pyenv which python"))` After considerable effort, lol.